# Solidity: What is the best name/term for the collection of contracts in a .sol file?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

What is the best name/term for the collection of contracts in a .sol file? 
...for example, is module the best word to use?

Answer (score 0):

module - don't think so. Because module is about functionality, not about type of files. Modules can be the *.sol files themselves. I would prefer something like this - collection, library, package, set